# Importing complex modification doesn't work

Tags: karabiner

I want to swap command+backspace and option+backspace, so that command+backspace deletes a word, and option+backspace deletes a line. Apparently someone already solved the issue and has already written the .json file for this. I found it [here](https://madogiwa.github.io/KE-complex_modifications/) (you need to scroll down to "Exchange Command+Backward-Delete (delete current line) and Option+Backward-Delete (delete current word)"). So I simply imported it and enabled it in Karabiner, but nothing changed. I looked at the .json file, but I'm still new to Karabiner so I don't know if there is a problem with the file (maybe it's obsolete), or a problem with me using Karabiner.

There are 2 .json files. Here's the first one:

```
{
  "title": "Exchange Command+Backward-Delete (delete current line) and Option+Backward-Delete (delete current word)",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change Command+Backward-Delete and Option+Backward-Delete",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
              "modifiers": [
                "option"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change Option+Backward-Delete to Command+Backward-Delete",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "option"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
              "modifiers": [
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here's the second one:

```
{
  "title": "Exchange Command+Backward-Delete (delete current line) and Option+Backward-Delete (delete current word)",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change Command+Backward-Delete and Option+Backward-Delete",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
              "modifiers": [
                "option"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change Option+Backward-Delete to Command+Backward-Delete",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "from": {
            "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "option"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "any"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_or_backspace",
              "modifiers": [
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "type": "basic"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

One should be switching command+backspace with option+backspace, and the other should do the same with switching option+backspace with command+backspace.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the relevant details to the question so people don't have to jump off-site and scroll through a page to find the script. Or, even better, just copy/paste the one you have directly into the question.

Comment: I edited the question and added the 2 .json files